# Continue buffering paused HTML5 video in background (or unfocused) Safari tab

Tags: safari, video

I've been searching for a while to figure out a way to get Safari to keep loading (buffering) paused videos when the tab containing the video isn't the one I'm currently focused on.

If I go to another tab in Safari to read something while the video loads, the video stops loading. But also if I leave the tab in the front and go to another application to do something while the video is loading the video stops loading.

This definitely happens every time when I'm dealing with Vimeo. I think it happens other times, but I can't think of any places to try out. I don't use flash player, so this might only be happening with html5 video players.

I found [a page that promised to help with loading background tabs](http://mediabaron.com/blog/2011/07/27/how-to-get-safari-to-load-tabbed-pages-in-the-background-in-mac-osx-lion/?doing_wp_cron=1415995459.4841959476470947265625), but it relates to Lion (I'm on Yosemite) and the person seems to be saying that tabs don't load at all in the background. I'm not having that problem (and unsurprisingly the solution didn't work).

Comment: Loading means continue playing or what ? just tried it on Firefox with Vimeo video and it keeps running.

Comment: Just tired it on Safari with Vimeo playing video, and switching to another tab does not stop the play.

Comment: if I pause it it stops, so what is the point.

Comment: If I do not stop the play, and switch to another tab it continues to play. If I stop the play it stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18666/discussion-between-dwightk-and-buscar).

Comment: OK, my problem was I am using Adobe Flash and not HTML5. I believe HTML5 will move its focus to a new site, not opening a new instance, while Adobe will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the setting you’re looking for is **Disable Hidden Page Timer Throttling**, located under **Debug** → **Miscellaneous Flags**.

If you haven’t enabled the Safari **Debug** menu yet, triple-click the following line and paste it into a **Terminal** session:
`defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1`

Now completely quit Safari, then reopen it. The **Debug** menu should become available.

If you’re on Safari Technology Preview, the Terminal command is:
`defaults write com.apple.SafariTechnologyPreview IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1`

Comment: I also had to _Disable App Nap_ and restart Safari for PiP to work with Safari in the background (or in another space).

Answer (score 0):

Just go click on "Preferences" in Safari menu. Then, in "Advanced" tab, uncheck the thing about plugins in background. Good luck

Comment: "Stop Plugins to save power"?

Comment: this doesn't work